# Angular - Why does the # sign at z-index always appear?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I don't know what is wrong with my code but I have set a z-index in my css like this:

```
.mat-mini-fab {
   position: absolute;
   right: 5px;
   top: 4px;
   z-index: 999;
   box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

But whenever I go to my site, the z-index is not applied and when I check in the developer console, there is always a # in front of the value so like this `z-index: #999`. I don't know where this comes from??

Tested in Chrome and Firefox.
I am definitely sure in the code I never set the # before.

When I change this to 1000, there is no #, but below 1000 the # always is there... what kind of bug is this??

[image]

Comment: curiously - does this happen even with `z-index: 999 !important;` ?

Comment: Without more info it looks like your bundler/minifier/linter is detecting `999` as a hex value and trying to format it? How are you bundling your CSS? Where does the `[_ngcontent-elm-c129]` come from?

Comment: @chazsolo it comes from angular.

Comment: `z-index: 999 !important;` did not help. How can I check my bundler/minifier/linter? I am using a simple Angular project

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the versions of your Angular deps?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20870

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after switching to Angular 12. Looks like a problem with the way Webpack bundles. I added the top limit of the z-index, then it did not add the #.

```
  z-index: 2147483647;
```